# Intellij Rider: Breakpoints are completely missing for C++ project

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

Can't find the inline breakpoints for the C++ project in Intellij Rider. Clicking on the field on the left next to the line does nothing.

At the same time just opened  C# project and breakpoints are there. This is on the same instance of Rider.

Does it automatically look for the linked files and if they are not set up correctly, disables the breaskpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using [Rider for Unreal Engine](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/rider-unreal/). Regular version of Rider does not include C++ support - Rider for UE is still in Early Preview.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [Clion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) for C++ project. Rider IDE is usually used for C Sharp project. That can be a problem when you can't set breakpoint for C++ project

Comment: Good suggestion. Rider feels faster though and for me personally easier to get in to as it is more akeen to idea than Clion. But I will try again with CLion and see if I can get used to it.